# How to use WPF Telerik DataPager to load just size of PageSize?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using WPF Telerik GridView and DataPager in my project and i want to show a list of Items using this two controls.

I bound *Source* property of DataPager to *Items* property of the DataGrid (Like original demo).
my problem is: datapager loads all of entities in first call!. i want to load just amount of pagesize (20).

this is my code:

```
private void LoadProductsBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (AccountingContext context = new AccountingContext())
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => grdProducts.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Item>(context.Items.Include("UnitType").Include("Producer").ToList())));
    }
}

<telerik:RadDataPager Name="dataPager" PageSize="20" Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=grdProducts}" />

    <telerik:RadGridView Name="grdProducts">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static sr:EntitiesResource.ID}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static sr:EntitiesResource.ProductName}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static sr:EntitiesResource.Producer}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Producer.Name}" Width="200" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static sr:EntitiesResource.UnitType}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=UnitType.Name}" Width="150" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static sr:EntitiesResource.Price}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}" Width="150" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static sr:EntitiesResource.Description}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Width="*" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datapager by default works on a collection of data and internally splits into the specified page size. So you are right in saying that it gets everything and then pages. But for your scenario where you want to retrieve data = pagesize on each page change, you would need to customize the rad data pager Source. Basically the PageSource is of type IPagedCollectionView. So you would need to create a class which implements IEnumerable and Telerik.Windows.Data.IPagedCollectionView interfaces, provide implementation for those interface members and you will be able to achieve your requirement. Its pretty lengthy to explain it here. But what i can suggest is - download RadControls for WPF and look at Endless Paging using DataPager. That provides the requirement that you are looking for.

Hope i was able to provide you with some pointers to your requirement.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)

Comment: Then you have to download a demo tool after installing the rad controls, I am not even sure you need the 'rad' controls... So much work when all I need is a simple example of how to bind the  IPagedCollectionView.. Demo Tool: http://demos.telerik.com/wpf/